# How can I reduce IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Foo>> to IEnumerable<Foo>?

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

Sorry for the weird caption. What I'm trying to achieve is simple:

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Foo>> listoflist;
IEnumerable<Foo> combined = listoflist.CombineStuff();
```

Example:

```
{{0, 1}, {2, 3}} => {0, 1, 2, 3}
```

I'm positive there is a Linq expression for this...

Sidenote: The lists may be large.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As leppie says, you want [`Enumerable.SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx). The simplest form would be:

```
 combined = listOfList.SelectMany(x => x);
```

In query expressions, `SelectMany` is called when you have more than one `from` clause, so an alternative would be:

```
 combined = from x in listOfList
            from y in x
            select y;
```

Comment: I wonder why MS didnt overload all the extension methods taking no parameters and using identity instead. Guess type inference wont work so nice then.

Comment: Yes, type inference would get tricky - at least pre-covariance. After that it would be simpler though.

Answer (score 2):

> SelectMany()

OK